# Set Process 'image name' and 'description' wtih C#

Tags: c#, process

I want to go into as much detail as possible so this question is easily understood and *`answer-able`*

Essentially I need a way set up the *process name* and *process description* with C# on the applications *startup*.

Here is an example of what I would like changing;

**Note:** I want to set my OWN C# applications image and description with CODE.

[image: Example]

I want to be able to change the following things in my application on startup.
*`Image Name`* in the Processes list, as well as the *`Description`* in the Processes list.
So far in my C# application i can set the process name with the properties but id rather be able to set it with some sort of code snippet *(as well as the description)*.

I hope this has been a information question and you good clever people at stackoverflow can help.

Comment: To be clear: You want to change your own executable's name and description; not that of Google Chrome or another 3rd party application?

Comment: @SteveMayne Yah.  I was thinking like you, but see the red text at the bottom of the window

Comment: @Cacoon:  have you seen this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055987/c-how-to-set-an-projects-executable-processname

Comment: Imagine if you could do this in code. Your program could change its title or description at any time ... to anything. Interesting.

Comment: You may also check this link: [How to Change a Process Name on Windows Task Manager](http://www.ehow.com/how_6449869_change-name-windows-task-manager.html), although that's not from `c#`.

Comment: No, my own application
And id like to do it in code.

Comment: Well, it seems there's a way to do it from Visual Basic [Change your Process name in Windows Task Manager!](https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=66443&lngWId=1). If you want you may dig in and adapt it to `c#`. I'm no VB expert, but it seems that this solution requires hooking into the Task Manager window based on a timer and modify the controls on it, which is... well, I'll not name it :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't change the image name. It's the name of your executable file.
The process description, however, can be changed on your C# project assembly info:

Right click on your C# project in Visual Studio > Properties > Application > Assembly information > Title.

You can't change the description at runtime from code: the OS loads the description at startup from the [Version Information file resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The Image Name property is the name of the executable itself (ie Foobar.exe), the Description property is the Title of the application in the Assembly Information dialogue box, as shown below:

[image: Info]

At this point, when you run your program, you will see two entries into the task manager as shown below:

[image: Task Manager]

One will say the name you specified in the Title box, the other will say vshost32.exe as the description. To fix this, untick the option called **Enable the Visual Studio hosting process** in the project properties page.

Comment: When i change the decription there it doesnt change it in the task manager.

Comment: Are you changing the description here? You need to change the title

Comment: I changed both the title and description in the assembly information in Properties > Application > Assembly Information

Comment: Works for me, are you debugging? You won't see this while debugging, you will see vshost32.exe instead

Comment: I build it, go to the debug folder and run as admin and i still get "vshost32.exe" as the description :s

Answer (score 0):

As close as I can come to an answer is to pragmatically create a new executable with the desired name and description launch that executable then allow your launch process to die.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer.
But how can i set the description of an application with code. (My applications that is)

Answer (score -1):

Try using your application as a 'host' for another app.
As soon as the application is launched, it downloads a file from a dropbox link (a direct download link) and saves it locally, (In the temp folder probably).
Then our application launches that application and then kills itself with maybe an error.
now the process running on that one would be gone, and we have a new process with our set title and description. Easy!