# Set Image Name and Description for a process using System.Diagnostics.Process()

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, taskmanager

How to set Image Name and Description for a process when using System.Diagnostics.Process() to start a process?

So that it appears in the Windows task manager with desired name and description.

For Example currently I am invoking some console application as shown below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int incVal = 0;

        Process[] process = null;

        try
        {
            process = new Process[Properties.Settings.Default.TargetLayers.Length];

            for (incVal = 0; incVal < Properties.Settings.Default.TargetLayers.Split(',').Length; incVal++)
            {
                process[incVal] = new Process();

                process[incVal].StartInfo.FileName = "PMSchedulerTask.exe";

                process[incVal].StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + Properties.Settings.Default.TargetLayers.Split(',')[incVal] + "$" + Properties.Settings.Default.TableMVRelation.Split('|')[incVal] + "\"";

                process[incVal].Start();
            }

            for (incVal = 0; incVal < Properties.Settings.Default.TargetLayers.Split(',').Length; incVal++)
            {
                process[incVal].WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to have each process shown in the task manager with different Image Name and Description.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Process 'image name' and 'description' wtih C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277816/set-process-image-name-and-description-wtih-c-sharp)

Comment: No its not duplicate here the context is bit different.

Comment: what's the reason  of doing this

Comment: I want to have same exe with different Image name and description as I am invoking it with parent exe with different parameters.

Answer (score 4):

These names are extracted by task manager from the executable image the process was started from. There is no setting to override this. Windows doesn't even know these strings exist. They are just part of the PE structure of the executable used to launch the process.

You could create a wrapper executable if you really need to do this.

Comment: @BridewinD.P. Well the image name is the name of the executable on disk so ... yes, [just rename it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @ta.speot.is No that won't work! It will rename all the process with Image name "PMSchedulerTask.exe" to the new name which was provided to the api. I am trying to have separate Image name for each of the process.

Comment: It was a joke because this answer and [this linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277816/set-process-image-name-and-description-wtih-c-sharp) basically both say "no it can't be done" and you ask "can it be done". So my answer is oh yes! It can be done! Just rename the file.