# How do I change the process name(fully) on launch c#

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to make the process name of my application change at every launch, I've tried using Console.Title with a random string

```
Console.Title = randomString + "Loader";
```

Is there any way to make the name also run differently every time with a random string?

What I mean by this is, when you open Task Manager, you see that the process lets say we are running a .exe called `Google.exe`, and when you click the arrow it shows what is open inside. I'm trying to make it so that Google.exe launches in the form of a different app, (as if it was a notepad for example, but would still be a console app) This way my app stays different every time, and I can modify name string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing a programs process name in task manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914101/changing-a-programs-process-name-in-task-manager)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/405806/windows-task-manager-the-complete-guide/), Task Manager "names" the process based on the file name. I would suggest writing a separate program to act as the "handler" of the program who's name you want to modify, and changing the name of that exe in the handler, if you really need the process name in Task Manager to be different every time.